# How do I find the first string of differing case in an array?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings, and all contain at least one letter:

```
["abc", "FFF", "EEE"]
```

How do I find the index of the first string that is of a different case than any previous string in the array? The function should give `1` for the above since:

```
FFF".eql?("FFF".upcase)
```

and that condition isn't true for any previous string in the array, whereas:

```
["P", "P2F", "ccc", "DDD"]
```

should yield `2` since `"ccc"` is not capitalized and all its predecessors are.

I know how to find the first string that is capitalized using

```
string_tokens.find_index { |w| w == w.upcase }
```

but I can't figure out how to adjust the above to account for differing case.

Comment: `["abc", "FFF", "EEE"]` should return 1 or 0?

Comment: Should return "1" since "FFF" is the first string whose case differs from a previous element's.

Comment: Yes, now I've realized of it.

Comment: What if the array were `["666", "ccc", "DDD"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take each consecutive pair of elements and compare their upcase-ness. When they differ, you return the index.

```
def detect_case_change(ary)
  ary.each_cons(2).with_index(1) do |(a, b), idx|
    return idx if (a == a.upcase) != (b == b.upcase)
  end
  nil
end

detect_case_change ["abc", "FFF", "EEE"] # => 1
detect_case_change ["P", "P2F", "ccc", "DDD"] # => 2
```

Comment: You could replace `each_cons(2)` + logic + `return` by a `chunk_while`

Comment: Consider `...with_index(1)`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: could you elaborate on how can we use `chunk_while`, given that the requirement seems to be to find the index of first element with different case.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: oooohh, didn't know about this one, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This makes some assumptions about your data being composed entirely of 'A'..'Z' and 'a'..'z':

```
def find_case_mismatch(list)
  index = list.each_cons(2).to_a.index do |(a,b)|
    a[0].ord & 32 != b[0].ord & 32
  end

  index && index + 1
end
```

This compares the character values. 'A' differs from 'a' by one bit, and that bit is always in the same place (0x20).

Comment: "your data being composed entirely of 'A'..'Z' and 'a'..'z'" - actually, sample data in the question has digits in it. Although not at the first position.

Comment: Would the above still work for non A-Z characters, like a or e with the accent mark on them?

Comment: Yeah, this might be needlessly specific, but it might also be sufficient. Just putting it out there.

Comment: @Natalia Not all accented characters are actually the same letter. In some languages å and a are two totally different things, while in others é and e are roughly equivalent. This will not work on UTF-8 data, only 7-bit ASCII and only letters. If you're going into accented letters, then ß and æ are possibilities as well, so Æ might end up involved. This rabbit hole is super deep.

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable#chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) helps a lot for this task.

> Enumerates over the items, chunking them together based on the return
>   value of the block. Consecutive elements which return the same block
>   value are chunked together.

```
l1 = ["abc", "FFF", "EEE"]
l2 = ["P", "P2F", "ccc", "DDD"]
p l1.chunk{|s| s == s.upcase }.to_a
# [[false, ["abc"]], [true, ["FFF", "EEE"]]]
p l2.chunk{|s| s == s.upcase }.to_a
# [[true, ["P", "P2F"]], [false, ["ccc"]], [true, ["DDD"]]]
```

The fact that you need an index makes it a bit less readable, but here's an example. The desired index (if it exists) is the size of the first chunk:

```
p l1.chunk{|s| s == s.upcase }.first.last.size
# 1
p l2.chunk{|s| s == s.upcase }.first.last.size
# 2
```

If the case doesn't change at all, it returns the length of the whole array:

```
p %w(aaa bbb ccc ddd).chunk{|s| s == s.upcase }.first.last.size
# 4
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Clever!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each element (string) of the array contains at least one letter and only letters of the same case.

```
def first_case_change_index(arr)
  s = arr.map { |s| s[/[[:alpha:]]/] }.join
  (s[0] == s[0].upcase ? s.swapcase : s) =~ /[[:upper:]]/
end

first_case_change_index ["abc", "FFF", "EEE"] #=> 1
first_case_change_index ["P", "P2F", "ccc"]   #=> 2
first_case_change_index ["P", "P2F", "DDD"]   #=> nil
```

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = ["P", "2PF", "ccc"]

a = arr.map { |s| s[/[[:alpha:]]/] }
  #=> ["P", "P", "c"]
s = a.join
  #=> "PPc"
s[0] == s[0].upcase
  #=> "P" == "P"
  #=> true
t = s.swapcase
  #=> "ppC"
t =~ /[[:upper:]]/
  #=> 2
```

Here is another way.

```
def first_case_change_index(arr)
  look_for_upcase = (arr[0] == arr[0].downcase)
  arr.each_index.drop(1).find do |i|
    (arr[i] == arr[i].upcase) == look_for_upcase
  end
end
```